# Import private key certificate as exportable in azure app service

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service, pfx

I have a bit of code that signs and encrypts some text based on two certificates.
The code is working locally. An important detail to get the code to work was that I checked the checkbox "Mark the key as exportable" when importing the certificates on my developer machine.

I have now uploaded the certificates to my azure app service in the "Private Key Certificates" section below the app service TLS/SSL settings. But this upload functionality did not seem to have a feature similar to the important checkbox from before.

When running the code that was working locally in the context of my app service I get this exception:

`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException, Key not valid for use in specified state`

I expect that this is also the exception I would get locally, if I had not marked the certificate as exportable.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not supported. While you can use the private key to sign or decrypt, it's not exportable. This intended design is to prevent unintended delegation. I would advise access to those by other means. Perhaps uploading your certificate to [Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-export-certificate?tabs=azure-cli#exportable-and-non-exportable-keys) and [retrieving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) it from there.

Comment: My title is maybe a bit misleading. I am getting an error when trying to sign/encrypt: "Key not valid for use in specified state". I don't need the key to be exportable, but I assumed that I needed to mark it as such in order to avoid this error. I am using a third party library to create a signed and encrypted text based on the certificates. It is working fine on my local machine, but only when I mark the key as exportable. Could it be an issue in the way this library is using the certificates? (I know this is probably difficult to answer, since you don't know this library, but any ideas?)

Comment: No, because you're still uploading the cert for your app service to use. If the 3rd party library needs to use the cert as exportable, the same would apply.

Comment: Ok. So since all I need from the third-party library is encryption and signing, it should be possible to replace/rewrite the third party library and achieve my goal. But for some reason the third party library seems to require the cert to be exportable, making it a bad match with azure app service. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Nikolaj Is it still the case with Azure App Service?